# Horizontal nav-dropdown menu in Bootstrap 5 / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to create a horizontal dropdown menu for small screen, but all the threads I've read are outdated and don't work.

[image: Here is what I'm trying to create]

Comment: Here you [can see](https://codepen.io/seopainless/pen/popdgLp) how to create horizontal bootstrap dropdown menu

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
this will work if there's no other `custom` class in you project.

```css
:root {
  --primColor: #dcdcdc;
  --secoColor: #555555;
  --cornerRad: 4px;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--primColor);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.custom details {
     margin: 40px;
}
 .custom summary {
     writing-mode: vertical-lr;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 12px 10px;
     width: 23px;
     height: 17px;
     background-color: var(--primColor);
     border: 2px solid var(--secoColor);
     border-radius: var(--cornerRad);
     color: var(--secoColor);
     cursor: pointer;
     user-select: none;
     outline: none;
     transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
     position: relative;
     left: 95%;
}
 .custom summary::before, .custom summary::after {
     position: static;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}
 .custom summary::before {
     content: "";
}
 .custom summary::after {
     content: "III";
     letter-spacing: -1px;
}
 .custom summary:hover {
     transform: scale(1.1);
}
 .custom summary::marker {
     font-size: 0;
}
 .custom summary::-webkit-details-marker {
     display: none;
}
 .custom details[open] .menu {
     animation-name: menuAnim;
}
 .custom details[open] summary::before {
     content: "X";
}
 .custom details[open] summary::after {
     content: "";
}
 .custom .menu {
     height: 0;
     width: fit-content;
     border-radius: var(--cornerRad);
     background-color: var(--primColor);
     box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     margin-top: 8px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-between;
     overflow: hidden;
     animation: closeMenu 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
     width: 100%;
}
 .custom .menu a {
     padding: 12px 24px;
     margin: 0 16px;
     color: var(--secoColor);
     text-decoration: none;
     text-align: center;
     transition: filter 200ms linear 0s;
}
 .custom .menu a:nth-last-of-type(1) {
     border-bottom: none;
}
 .custom .menu a:hover {
     filter: brightness(200%);
}
 .custom details[open]::before {
     animation: fadeMe 300ms linear forwards;
}
 
@keyframes menuAnim {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: fit-content;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeMe {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
<details >
  <summary></summary>
  <nav class="menu">
    <a href="#link">Home</a>
    <a href="#link">Work</a>
    <a href="#link">Links</a>
    <a href="#link">Contact</a>
    <a href="#link">About</a>
  </nav>
</details>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not work I guess therefore you will need to write media queries for mobile devices.

For example! and then it might work on your mobile devices as well.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```